# multiply automatically cross values

Tags: sql-server, row, multiplication

I have a dataset which has 3 different values for each month, as you can see my dataset below. What I need to initialize is to multiply last date's third value with previous date's second value and multiply that with first value of one previous.

```
create table #sample_data(
ID  VARCHAR(10), val1 float, val2 float, val3 float);

insert into #sample_data values
  ('2018-01',0.9,0.6,0.3),
  ('2018-02',0.7,0.7,0.6),
  ('2018-03',0.1,0.2,0.4),
  ('2018-04',0.6,0.5,0.4),
  ('2018-05',0.5,0.6,0.7);
```

What I expect as result is:

- For last row: 0.7*0.5*0.1  = `0.035`
- For the previous one: 0.4*0.2*0.7 = `0.056`
- And one previous : 0.4*0.7*0.9 = `0,252`

and for others since I don't have 3 values it should return some default value.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, I guess it may help you and hope it works (well, I omitted the #'s):

```
SELECT s.id, s.val3 * COALESCE(s1.val2, 0) * COALESCE(s2.val1, 0)
FROM sample_data s
LEFT JOIN sample_data s2 ON s2.id < s.id AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sample_data s22 WHERE s22.id < s.id and s22.id > s2.id)
LEFT JOIN sample_data s3 ON s3.id < s2.id AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sample_data s33 WHERE s33.id < s2.id and s33.id > s3.id)
```

In this case it would default to 0, if there are any missing values. Perhaps you may also want to ignore the non-existent values, in this case you should take 1 as second argument of the `COALESCE`.

I assumed `val3` is not nullable, otherwise you might want to add a `COALESCE` here as well.